# How to enable DataGridView sorting when user clicks on the column header?

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview

I have a datagridview on my form and I populate it with this:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = students.Select(s => new { ID = s.StudentId, RUDE = s.RUDE, Nombre = s.Name, Apellidos = s.LastNameFather + " " + s.LastNameMother, Nacido = s.DateOfBirth })
                                   .OrderBy(s => s.Apellidos)
                                   .ToList();
```

Now, I use the s.Apellidos as the default sort, but I'd also like to allow users to sort when clicking on the column header.

This sort will **not** modify the data in any way, it's just a client side bonus to allow for easier searching for information when scanning the screen with their eyes.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: [DataGridView Sort Generic Lists by Click on Column Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37999726/3110834)

Answer (score 58):

Set all the column's (which can be sortable by users) SortMode property to Automatic

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = students.Select(s => new { ID = s.StudentId, RUDE = s.RUDE, Nombre = s.Name, Apellidos = s.LastNameFather + " " + s.LastNameMother, Nacido = s.DateOfBirth })
                                   .OrderBy(s => s.Apellidos)
                                   .ToList();

    foreach(DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
    
        column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
    }
```

**Edit:** As your datagridview is bound with a linq query, it will not be sorted. So please go through this `[404 dead link, see next section]` which explains how to create a sortable binding list and to then feed it as datasource to datagridview.

## Code as recovered from dead link

Link from above is 404-dead. I recovered the code from the Internet Wayback Machine [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170919124306/http://timvw.be/2007/02/22/presenting-the-sortablebindinglistt/) of the page.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SortableBindingList<person> persons = new SortableBindingList<person>();
    persons.Add(new Person(1, "timvw", new DateTime(1980, 04, 30)));
    persons.Add(new Person(2, "John Doe", DateTime.Now));

    this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    this.ColumnId.DataPropertyName = "Id";
    this.ColumnName.DataPropertyName = "Name";
    this.ColumnBirthday.DataPropertyName = "Birthday";
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = persons;
}
```

Comment: Since I want all columns to be sortable, is there a way to programatically iterate through each column and set this property?

Comment: @Niraj: I get a compiler error. I tried changing your answer to column.Name but it doesn't seem to modify the sorting in any way.

Comment: @Niraj: You edited your answer. Before it was just 'column' and it would fire a compiler error. I changed it to column.Name to make it work then you changed your answer. However this still doesn't allow me to sort the information.

Comment: @Sergio: So if I understand correctly, now you doesn't get any error but still the columns are not sortable.

Comment: @Niraj: Correct. I click on the column header and the rows don't order themselves.

Comment: @Sergio: Please refer this [link](http://www.timvw.be/2007/02/22/presenting-the-sortablebindinglistt/) and also take look at edit part of the answer

Comment: Btw, your `foreach` could be simpler: `foreach(DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns) column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;`

Comment: This answer helped me to figure out a solution for my problem. Here is my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43997006/6186647

Answer (score 29):

As Niraj suggested, use a **SortableBindingList**.  I've used this very successfully with the DataGridView.

Here's a link to the updated code I used - [Presenting the SortableBindingList - Take Two](http://www.timvw.be/2008/08/02/presenting-the-sortablebindinglistt-take-two/) - [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170923024649/http://timvw.be/2008/08/02/presenting-the-sortablebindinglistt-take-two/)

Just add the two source files to your project, and you'll be in business.

Source is in [SortableBindingList.zip](http://www.timvw.be/wp-content/code/csharp/SortableBindingList.zip) - `404 dead link`

Comment: This solution does not need LINQ and works in .net 2.0 and there are other useful functionality to be found in BindingList like change notification. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: The source does not exist anymore, is there anyway to update this?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @Arend I added links to the wayback machine archive of the dead link

Answer (score 15):

One more way to do this is using "System.Linq.Dynamic" library. You can get this library from [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/). No need of any custom implementations or sortable List :)

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
private bool sortAscending = false;

private void dataGridView_ColumnHeaderMouseClick ( object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e )
{
    if ( sortAscending )
        dataGridView.DataSource = list.OrderBy ( dataGridView.Columns [ e.ColumnIndex ].DataPropertyName ).ToList ( );
    else
        dataGridView.DataSource = list.OrderBy ( dataGridView.Columns [ e.ColumnIndex ].DataPropertyName ).Reverse ( ).ToList ( );
    sortAscending = !sortAscending;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, can't believe no one had given you positive feedback for this yet

Comment: Use `OrderByDescending` for the `else` case would be better.

Comment: works great! Dont forget to add ```dataGridView.ColumnHeaderMouseClick += dataGridView_ColumnHeaderMouseClick;``` And to implement this for BindingList which updates every time when data come in... you have to modify the code...
```dataGridView.DataSource = new BindingList<Data>(dataList.OrderBy(dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName).ToList());```

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to create a binding datasource. If you want to apply sorting for all of your columns, here is a more generic solution of mine;

```
private int _previousIndex;
private bool _sortDirection;

private void gridView_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == _previousIndex)
        _sortDirection ^= true; // toggle direction

    gridView.DataSource = SortData(
        (List<MainGridViewModel>)gridReview.DataSource, gridReview.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name, _sortDirection);

    _previousIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
}

public List<MainGridViewModel> SortData(List<MainGridViewModel> list, string column, bool ascending)
{
    return ascending ? 
        list.OrderBy(_ => _.GetType().GetProperty(column).GetValue(_)).ToList() :
        list.OrderByDescending(_ => _.GetType().GetProperty(column).GetValue(_)).ToList();
}
```

Make sure you subscribe your data grid to the event `ColumnHeaderMouseClick`. When the user clicks on the column it will sort by descending. If the same column header is clicked again, sorting will be applied by ascending.

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

**your data grid needs to be bound to a sortable list in the first place.**

Create this event handler:

```
    void MakeColumnsSortable_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        //Add this as an event on DataBindingComplete
        DataGridView dataGridView = sender as DataGridView;
        if (dataGridView == null)
        {
            var ex = new InvalidOperationException("This event is for a DataGridView type senders only.");
            ex.Data.Add("Sender type", sender.GetType().Name);
            throw ex;
        }

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView.Columns)
            column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
    }
```

And initialize the event of each of your datragrids like this:

```
        dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += MakeColumnsSortable_DataBindingComplete;
```

Comment: I liked the idea of using the DataBindingComplete event, but this doesn't address not having a sortable dataset. I've edited it to make it a bit more reusable

Answer (score 5):

You can use DataGridViewColoumnHeaderMouseClick event like this :

```
Private string order = String.Empty;
private void dgvDepartment_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (order == "d")
{
        order = "a";                
dataGridView1.DataSource = students.Select(s => new { ID = s.StudentId, RUDE = s.RUDE, Nombre = s.Name, Apellidos = s.LastNameFather + " " + s.LastNameMother, Nacido = s.DateOfBirth })   .OrderBy(s => s.Apellidos).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        order = "d";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = students.Select(s => new { ID = s.StudentId, RUDE = s.RUDE, Nombre = s.Name, Apellidos = s.LastNameFather + " " + s.LastNameMother, Nacido = s.DateOfBirth }.OrderByDescending(s => s.Apellidos)  .ToList()
    }
}
```

Comment: i wanna use this idea, but how can i manage which column header clicked? to sort datagridview order by that specific column name? thanks

Comment: @mr.dev.eloper - The DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs object contains the "ColumnIndex" property.

Answer (score 4):

there is quite simply solution when using Entity Framework (version 6 in this case). I'm not sure but it seems to `ObservableCollectionExtensions.ToBindingList<T>` method returns implementation of **sortable** binding list. I haven't found source code to confirm this supposition but object returning from this method works with `DataGridView` very well especially when sorting columns by clicking on its headers.

The code is very simply and relies only on .net and entity framework classes:

```cs
using System.Data.Entity;

IEnumerable<Item> items = MethodCreatingItems();

var observableItems = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Item>(items);
System.ComponentModel.BindingList<Item> source = observableItems.ToBindingList();

MyDataGridView.DataSource = source;
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using a DataTable.DefaultView as a DataSource. Then the line below.

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in gridview.Columns)
    {
       column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
    }
```

After that the gridview itself will manage sorting(Ascending or Descending is supported.)

Comment: Just passing a DataTable did the trick for me. No fiddling with addition modules etc. Thanky you so much!

Answer (score 3):

put this line in your windows form (on load or better in a public method like "binddata" ):

```
//
// bind the data and make the grid sortable 
//
this.datagridview1.MakeSortable( myenumerablecollection );
```

Put this code in a file called DataGridViewExtensions.cs (or similar)

```
// MakeSortable extension. 
// this will make any enumerable collection sortable on a datagrid view.  

//
// BEGIN MAKESORTABLE - Mark A. Lloyd
//
// Enables sort on all cols of a DatagridView 

//



    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public static class DataGridViewExtensions
    {
    public static void MakeSortable<T>(
        this DataGridView dataGridView, 
        IEnumerable<T> dataSource,
        SortOrder defaultSort = SortOrder.Ascending, 
        SortOrder initialSort = SortOrder.None)
    {
        var sortProviderDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Func<SortOrder, IEnumerable<T>>>();
        var previousSortOrderDictionary = new Dictionary<int, SortOrder>();
        var itemType = typeof(T);
        dataGridView.DataSource = dataSource;
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView.Columns)
        {
            object Provider(T info) => itemType.GetProperty(c.Name)?.GetValue(info);
            sortProviderDictionary[c.Index] = so => so != defaultSort ? 
                dataSource.OrderByDescending<T, object>(Provider) : 
                dataSource.OrderBy<T,object>(Provider);
            previousSortOrderDictionary[c.Index] = initialSort;
        }

        async Task DoSort(int index)
        {

            switch (previousSortOrderDictionary[index])
            {
                case SortOrder.Ascending:
                    previousSortOrderDictionary[index] = SortOrder.Descending;
                    break;
                case SortOrder.None:
                case SortOrder.Descending:
                    previousSortOrderDictionary[index] = SortOrder.Ascending;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }

            IEnumerable<T> sorted = null;
            dataGridView.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            dataGridView.Enabled = false;
            await Task.Run(() => sorted = sortProviderDictionary[index](previousSortOrderDictionary[index]).ToList());
            dataGridView.DataSource = sorted;
            dataGridView.Enabled = true;
            dataGridView.Cursor = Cursors.Default;

        }

        dataGridView.ColumnHeaderMouseClick+= (object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) => DoSort(index: e.ColumnIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

KISS : Keep it simple, stupid

*Way A:*
Implement an own [SortableBindingList](http://www.timvw.be/2007/02/22/presenting-the-sortablebindinglistt/) class when like to use **DataBinding** and **sorting**.

*Way B:*
Use a **List<string>** sorting works also but does not work with **DataBinding**.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a class which contains all properties you need, and populate them in the constructor

   ```
   class Student
   {
       int _StudentId;
       public int StudentId {get;}
       string _Name;
       public string Name {get;}
       ...

       public Student(int studentId, string name ...)
       { _StudentId = studentId; _Name = name; ... }
   }
   ```
2. Create an IComparer < Student > class, to be able to sort

   ```
   class StudentSorter : IComparer<Student>
   {
       public enum SField {StudentId, Name ... }
       SField _sField; SortOrder _sortOrder;

       public StudentSorder(SField field, SortOrder order)
       { _sField = field; _sortOrder = order;}

       public int Compare(Student x, Student y)
       {
           if (_SortOrder == SortOrder.Descending)
           {
               Student tmp = x;
               x = y;
               y = tmp;
           }

           if (x == null || y == null)
               return 0;

           int result = 0;
           switch (_sField)
           {
               case SField.StudentId:
                   result = x.StudentId.CompareTo(y.StudentId);
                   break;
               case SField.Name:
                   result = x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
                   break;
                   ...
           }

           return result;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Within the form containing the datagrid add

   ```
   ListDictionary sortOrderLD = new ListDictionary(); //if less than 10 columns
   private SortOrder SetOrderDirection(string column)
   {
       if (sortOrderLD.Contains(column))
       {
           sortOrderLD[column] = (SortOrder)sortOrderLD[column] == SortOrder.Ascending ? SortOrder.Descending : SortOrder.Ascending;
       }
       else
       {
           sortOrderLD.Add(column, SortOrder.Ascending);
       }

       return (SortOrder)sortOrderLD[column];
   }
   ```
4. Within datagridview_ColumnHeaderMouseClick event handler do something like this

   ```
   private void dgv_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
   {
       StudentSorter sorter = null;
       string column = dGV.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName; //Use column name if you set it
       if (column == "StudentId")
       {
           sorter = new StudentSorter(StudentSorter.SField.StudentId, SetOrderDirection(column));
       }
       else if (column == "Name")
       {
           sorter = new StudentSorter(StudentSorter.SField.Name, SetOrderDirection(column));
       }

       ...

       List<Student> lstFD = datagridview.DataSource as List<Student>;
       lstFD.Sort(sorter);
       datagridview.DataSource = lstFD;
       datagridview.Refresh();
   }
   ```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you get an error message like

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

if you work with SortableBindingList, your code probably uses some loops over DataGridView rows and also try to access the empty last row! (BindingSource = null)

If you don't need to allow the user to add new rows directly in the DataGridView this line of code easily solve the issue:

```
InitializeComponent();
m_dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false; // after components initialized
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody still looks for it, I did it on VS 2008 C#.

On the Event ColumnHeaderMouseClick, add a databinding for the gridview, and send the order by field like a parameter. You can get the clicked field as follows:

```
dgView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name
```

In my case the header's names are similar to view field names.

Answer (score 0):

I have a BindingList<> object bind as a data source to dataGridView.

```
BindingList x1;
x1 = new BindingList<sourceObject>();
BindingSource bsx1 = new BindingSource();
bsx1.DataSource = x1;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bsx1;
```

When I clicked the column header, no sorting takes place. 
I used the SortableBindingList answer provided by Tom Bushell. 
Having included two source files into my project

1. SortableBindingList.cs
2. PropertyComparer.cs

Then this change is made to my code:

```
Be.Timvw.Framework.ComponentModel.SortableBindingList x1;                       // 1
x1 = new Be.Timvw.Framework.ComponentModel.SortableBindingList<sourceObject>(); // 2
BindingSource bsx1 = new BindingSource();
bsx1.DataSource = x1;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bsx1;
```

After these changes I performed a build on my program. I am now able to sort by clicking the column headers. Only two lines need changing, they are highlighted in the code snippet above by trailing comments.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I had set my `DataSource` as an `object`, which is why it didn't get sorted. After changing from `object` to a `DataTable` it workd well without any code complement.

Answer (score 0):

If using a `DataTable`: `dgv.DataSource = (DataTable)table`

You can automatically enable Sorting for objects that contain the `IComparable` Interface. After creating the DataTable, when adding the columns be sure to set the type also to at least `object`:
`table.Columns.Add("ColumnName", typeof(object))`

Otherwise, if you do Not specifically give it a type, it converts the object to a string.

**I spent a fair amount of time creating a `dgv_ColumnHeaderMouseClick()` event because it was Not sorting the `DataGridView` correctly, then to find that all you need to do is specify the type for the column name, and it sorts properly.** And the reason it was not sorting correctly previously was because without specifying the type for DataTable columns, it will convert objects to strings.

Answer (score 0):

Just instead of passing a list to the datagrid, you store the search result as a datatable.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = students
  .Select(s => new { 
       ID = s.StudentId, 
       RUDE = s.RUDE, 
       Nombre = s.Name, 
       Apellidos = s.LastNameFather + " " + s.LastNameMother, 
       Nacido = s.DateOfBirth })
  .OrderBy(s => s.Apellidos)
  .ToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Totally "generic" version, no binding needed, type-free, just a little reflection.
Copy-paste and enjoy.

```
        bool sortDirection;

        void DataGrid_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var dataGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
            var colName = dataGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
            var dataSource = ((IEnumerable)dataGrid.DataSource).Cast<object>().ToList();

            sortDirection = !sortDirection;

            if (sortDirection)
                this.dataGrid.DataSource = dataSource.OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(colName).GetValue(x, null)).ToList();
            else
                this.dataGrid.DataSource = dataSource.OrderByDescending(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(colName).GetValue(x, null)).ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all that you need to do in order to achieve sorting on DataGrid.

[Note: Replace the Data Source from "GenericReportDetail" to the data source (list of items) that you want to bind with your data grid and dataGridView1 to your dataGridView name]

```
private int _previousIndex;
private bool _sortDirection;

private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(global::System.Object sender, global::System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == _previousIndex)
            {
                // Toggle the sort direction if the same column is clicked again
                _sortDirection = !_sortDirection;
            }
            else
            {
                // Reset the sort direction if a different column is clicked
                _sortDirection = true;
                dataGridView1.Columns[_previousIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.None;
            }

            // Sort the data and set the sorted list as the data source for 
    the DataGridView
    List<GenericReportDetail> sortedList = 
    SortData((List<GenericReportDetail>)dataGridView1.DataSource, 
    dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name, _sortDirection);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = sortedList;

                // Set the sort glyph direction for the sorted column
            dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = _sortDirection ? SortOrder.Ascending : SortOrder.Descending;

            // Store the current column index as the previous index
            _previousIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : "+ex.Message, "Error");
        }
    }
    public List<GenericReportDetail> SortData(List<GenericReportDetail> list, string column, bool ascending)
    {
        return ascending ?
            list.OrderBy(_ => _.GetType().GetProperty(column).GetValue(_)).ToList() :
            list.OrderByDescending(_ => _.GetType().GetProperty(column).GetValue(_)).ToList();
    }

//And add the following in your page load event, 
//it will sort you first column of the dataGrid and display an arrow sign (sort glyph direction) on the column header.

 string firstColumnName = dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName;
 List<GenericReportDetail> sortedList = 
SortData((List<GenericReportDetail>)dataGridView1.DataSource, firstColumnName, true);
 dataGridView1.DataSource = sortedList;

 // Set the sort glyph direction for the first column
 dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending;
 _previousIndex = 0;
 _sortDirection = true;
```