# Sorting on databound gridview is not working

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview in my winForm application which is linked to an entity model. This is the code for loading data in datagridview:

```
var rawData = context.GetType().GetProperty(TableName).GetValue(context, null);
var truncatedData = ((IQueryable<object>)rawData).ToList();
crudBindingSource.DataSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = truncatedData };
dgvLoadTable.DataSource = crudBindingSource;
dgvLoadTable.Refresh();
```

Now I want to sort the data upon columnHeader click. I tried this:

```
private void dgvLoadTable_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
  DataGridViewColumn column = dgvLoadTable.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
  DataGridViewColumn _sortColumn = null;
  bool isSortAscending = false;
  isSortAscending = (_sortColumn == null || isSortAscending == false);
  string direction = isSortAscending ? "ASC" : "DESC";
  crudBindingSource.DataSource = context.TableName.OrderBy(
  string.Format("it.{0} {1}", column.DataPropertyName, direction)).ToList();

  if (_sortColumn != null) _sortColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.None;
    column.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = isSortAscending ? SortOrder.Ascending : SortOrder.Descending;
   //exception here
  _sortColumn = column;
 }
```

but, this is throwing exception: Operation can only be performed on cells that belong to a DataGridView control. What should I do?

Comment: isn't datagrid doing the sorting already when you enable it? are you trying to do some custom sorting?

Comment: No, it doesn't sort on it's own, I'm trying to do that manually

Comment: You don't need to implement you own sorting algorithm, try to make the data source sortable. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5556482/815938) may help you.

Comment: I think you need to learn some things, there are some unnecessary statements in your code

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/0868ft3z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of your datagridview and you get:

```
DataGridViewColumn column = dgvLoadTable.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
ListSortDirection direction = isSortAscending ? ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;

dgvLoadTable.Sort(column, direction);
```

Comment: you can write SortAscending.checked(radiobutton) instead of a variable which we don't know how to assign it (according to post it's assigned inside mouseclick event)

Comment: DataGridView control cannot be sorted if it is bound to an IBindingList that does not support sorting

Comment: Here is a link to a previous post related to DataGridView sorting [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699642/how-to-sort-databound-datagridview-column?rq=1)