# Make all datagridview columns sortable

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a Windows form with a `datagridview`.

**The ideal situation:**

User clicks on any of the nine columns, and the program sorts all the data, if the clicked column contains numbers, I would like the lowest number on the top. If the clicked column contains a string I would like it to be sorted Alphabetically (A-Z).

**What I have right now:**

I saw an old question on Stack Overflow where the OP how to sort the datagridview when clicking "a" header. The difference with mine is that I want my datagridview to be sortable by any of the nine columns.

I have this code, stolen from the question I found:

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = listPlayers.Select(s => new { voornaam = s.Voornaam, 
                                                        Achternaam = s.Achternaam, 
                                                        positie = s.Positie, 
                                                        Nationaltieit = s.Nationaliteit, 
                                                        Leeftijd = s.Age, 
                                                        Aanval = s.Aanval, 
                                                        Verdediging = s.Verdediging, 
                                                        Gemiddeld = s.Gemiddeld, 
                                                        waarde = s.TransferWaarde })
                                   .OrderBy(s => s.Achternaam)
                                   .ToList();

foreach(DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView2.Columns)
    {
        dataGridView2.Columns[column.Name].SortMode =
                                  DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
    }
```

This only lets the user order by "Achternaam" when he clicks one of the nine columns. What I want is when the user clicks on the Nationaliteit column, the data gets sorted with the An on top. And so on for every column

This is the listplayers list:

```
namespace SimulatorSimulator
{
    class SpelerData
    {
        public string Voornaam { get; set; }
        public string Achternaam { get; set; }
        public string Positie { get; set; }
        public string Nationaliteit { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public int Aanval { get; set; }
        public int Verdediging { get; set; }
        public int Gemiddeld { get; set; }
        public string TransferWaarde { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And in the main class:

```
 List<SpelerData> listPlayers = new List<SpelerData>();
```

Some dummy data:

```
Romelu;Lukaku;Aanvaller;Belgie;22;87;12;50;41.000.000,00    
Raheem ;Sterling;Aanvaller;Engeland;21;84;30;57;35.000.000,00    
Zlatan ;Ibrahimovic;Aanvaller;Zweden;34;87;21;54;34.500.000,00
```

Comment: @KevinTinnemans Please consider Ivan Stoev's comment on Ian's answer more carefully.  I might get flamed for saying so, and this might be misconstrued since I posted my own answer, but the accepted answer will not help you become a better developer in any way.  Brute force is a jumping off point, and is what you fall back to when you can't come up with a better solution - for which there are several for this particular problem.  This will lead to bad practices, and unmanageable code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do think that the simplest way for your case would be to put up your data in a `Database` table. This way, you could simply use this as the `data source` for your `dataGridView2`, and you will be able to do your sorting easily by clicking the header column.

An alternative way will be to use [SortableBindingList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553100/how-to-enable-datagridview-sorting-when-user-clicks-on-the-column-header) ([article](http://www.timvw.be/2007/02/22/presenting-the-sortablebindinglistt/)) as the other answer has also suggested.

But if both options are not among your choices, the next simplest way I could think of is by creating event from `ColumnHeaderMouseClick`, and then you could list your sorting accordingly by making use of `e.ColumnIndex` and right "mapping" (Dictionary) to your prepared `IEnumerable<SpelerData>`

So, in your form load, you do something like this:

```
Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<SpelerData>> queryDict = new Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<SpelerData>>(); //Prepare a dictionary of query
private void form_load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    dataGridView2.DataSource = listPlayers.OrderBy(x => x.Achternaam).ToList();
    queryDict.Add(0, listPlayers.OrderBy(x => x.Voornaam));
    queryDict.Add(1, listPlayers.OrderBy(x => x.Achternaam));
    queryDict.Add(2, listPlayers.OrderBy(x => x.Positie));
    queryDict.Add(3, listPlayers.OrderBy(x => x.Nationaliteit));
    queryDict.Add(4, listPlayers.OrderBy(x => x.Age));
    queryDict.Add(5, listPlayers.OrderBy(x => x.Aanval));
    queryDict.Add(6, listPlayers.OrderBy(x => x.Verdediging));
    queryDict.Add(7, listPlayers.OrderBy(x => x.Gemiddeld));
    queryDict.Add(8, listPlayers.OrderBy(x => x.TransferWaarde));
}
```

And then in the `ColumnHeaderMouseClick` event, simply do:

```
private void dataGridView2_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
    dataGridView2.DataSource = queryDict[e.ColumnIndex].ToList();
}
```

And you will get the behavior that you want.

Note that since `IEnumerable` is delayed execution, the early preparation of the `Dictionary` will not have impact on the performance at all. The only thing you need to add are the 9 lines of code in the form_Load to prepare the dictionary and 1 line of code in your `dataGridView2_ColumnHeaderMouseClick` event. This is the simplest solution apart from the two I mentioned earlier which I could think of.

Comment: *"This is the simplest solution apart from the two I mentioned earlier which I could think of."* While this works for the specific case, it's more a workaround than a solution. What if you need the same for another grid - yet another 10 lines of code? Third grid etc.? Also reassigning the data source is highly inefficient and has a side effects. `IBindingList` and `IBindingListView` interfaces are specifically made to handle this and similar scenarios. Creating a base generic class might look more coding, but it's worth because it's a one time effort and can be reused on thousands of places.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a SortableBindingList

```
SortableBindingList<T> list = new SortableBindingList<T>();

//Add items to list

dataGridView.DataSource = list ;
```

This will allow sorting when clicking on the column header

```
public class SortableBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, PropertyComparer<T>> comparers;
    private bool isSorted;
    private ListSortDirection listSortDirection;
    private PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor;

    public SortableBindingList()
        : base(new List<T>())
    {
        this.comparers = new Dictionary<Type, PropertyComparer<T>>();
    }

    public SortableBindingList(IEnumerable<T> enumeration)
        : base(new List<T>(enumeration))
    {
        this.comparers = new Dictionary<Type, PropertyComparer<T>>();
    }

    protected override bool SupportsSortingCore
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    protected override bool IsSortedCore
    {
        get { return this.isSorted; }
    }

    protected override PropertyDescriptor SortPropertyCore
    {
        get { return this.propertyDescriptor; }
    }

    protected override ListSortDirection SortDirectionCore
    {
        get { return this.listSortDirection; }
    }

    protected override bool SupportsSearchingCore
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    protected override void ApplySortCore(PropertyDescriptor property, ListSortDirection direction)
    {
        List<T> itemsList = (List<T>)this.Items;

        Type propertyType = property.PropertyType;
        PropertyComparer<T> comparer;
        if (!this.comparers.TryGetValue(propertyType, out comparer))
        {
            comparer = new PropertyComparer<T>(property, direction);
            this.comparers.Add(propertyType, comparer);
        }

        comparer.SetPropertyAndDirection(property, direction);
        itemsList.Sort(comparer);

        this.propertyDescriptor = property;
        this.listSortDirection = direction;
        this.isSorted = true;

        this.OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));
    }

    protected override void RemoveSortCore()
    {
        this.isSorted = false;
        this.propertyDescriptor = base.SortPropertyCore;
        this.listSortDirection = base.SortDirectionCore;

        this.OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));
    }

    protected override int FindCore(PropertyDescriptor property, object key)
    {
        int count = this.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            T element = this[i];
            if (property.GetValue(element).Equals(key))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use reflection, you can do something like the following.

**NOTE:** I'm assuming you're using the [`DataGridView.ColumnHeaderMouseClick Event`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadermouseclick(v=vs.110).aspx), but that doesn't change the core of this approach.  The point is you need to dynamically identify the string value representing the name of the column you want to `OrderBy`.  You could hardcode this association if you really needed/wanted to.

```
private void dataGridView2_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(
    object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    var sortCol = dataGridView2.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
    var colName = sortCol.Name;

    dataGridView2.DataSource = listPlayers.Select(s => new { voornaam = s.Voornaam, Achternaam = s.Achternaam, positie = s.Positie, Nationaltieit = s.Nationaliteit, Leeftijd = s.Age, Aanval = s.Aanval, Verdediging = s.Verdediging, Gemiddeld = s.Gemiddeld, waarde = s.TransferWaarde })
                                          .OrderBy(s => typeof(SpelerData).GetProperty(colName))
                                          .ToList();
    ...
}
```