# DataGridView - Sort Generic Lists by Click on Column Headers

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

When I assign a `List<MyClass>` to `DataSource` of a `DataGridView`, when I click on column headers, nothing happens and sorting doesn't work; but if I use a `DataTable` as data source, the sorting works perfect when a header is clicked.

The question is: Which kind of collection types should be used to enable sorting in `DataGridView` just like it works with `DataTable` when I click on column header?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable DataGridView sorting when user clicks on the column header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553100/how-to-enable-datagridview-sorting-when-user-clicks-on-the-column-header)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**How Sorting works in a data-bound DataGridView**

When you click on a column header in a data-bound `DataGridView` which its automatic sorting is enabled, first it checks if the list behind of the `DataSource` property is [`IBindingList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist(v=vs.110).aspx), then using [`SupportsSorting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.supportssorting(v=vs.110).aspx) checks if the list supports sorting. Then it calls [`ApplySort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.applysort(v=vs.110).aspx) method to sort the list.

When you use a [`DataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) as data source of the grid, the list behind the data source is actually a [`DataView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview(v=vs.110).aspx) which implements `IBindingList` that supports sorting.

To have automatic support for sorting in a `DataGridView`, the list should implement `IBindingList` and its members which are related to sort.

**Enable sorting in a BindingList<T>**

To have typed list implementation of `IBindingList` which also supports sorting, a good option is deriving from [`BindingList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx). It implements `IBindingList` but it doesn't support sorting by default. You can override it's methods and properties which are related to sorting: `SupportsSortingCore`, `IsSortedCore`, `SortPropertyCore`, `SortDirectionCore` and `ApplySortCore`.

**Existing Implementations**

There are some implementations around:

- [`SortableBindingList<T>`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/02104044fae2aca5d3a1f50f55f4af940a3c64a8/src/EntityFramework/Internal/SortableBindingList%60.cs) implementation which is used in Entity Framework.
- `SortableSearchableList<T>` which is published in an [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480736.aspx)
- If you are using Entity Framework, [`ToBindingList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.observablecollectionextensions.tobindinglist(v=vs.113).aspx) method of the [`Local`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696248(v=vs.113).aspx) property of `DbSet<T>` returns a sortable `BindingList<T>`.

### SortableBindingList

Here is an implementation which is borrowed from Microsoft internal implementations with some small changes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class SortableBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>
{
    private bool _isSorted;
    private ListSortDirection _sortDirection;
    private PropertyDescriptor _sortProperty;

    public SortableBindingList(List<T> list)
        : base(list)
    {
    }
    protected override void ApplySortCore(PropertyDescriptor prop, ListSortDirection direction)
    {
        if (PropertyComparer.CanSort(prop.PropertyType))
        {
            ((List<T>)Items).Sort(new PropertyComparer(prop, direction));
            _sortDirection = direction;
            _sortProperty = prop;
            _isSorted = true;
            OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));
        }
    }
    protected override void RemoveSortCore()
    {
        _isSorted = false;
        _sortProperty = null;
    }

    protected override bool IsSortedCore
    {
        get { return _isSorted; }
    }

    protected override ListSortDirection SortDirectionCore
    {
        get { return _sortDirection; }
    }

    protected override PropertyDescriptor SortPropertyCore
    {
        get { return _sortProperty; }
    }

    protected override bool SupportsSortingCore
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    internal class PropertyComparer : Comparer<T>
    {
        private readonly IComparer _comparer;
        private readonly ListSortDirection _direction;
        private readonly PropertyDescriptor _prop;
        private readonly bool _useToString;

        public PropertyComparer(PropertyDescriptor prop, ListSortDirection direction)
        {
            if (!prop.ComponentType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
            {
                throw new MissingMemberException(typeof(T).Name, prop.Name);
            }

            Debug.Assert(CanSort(prop.PropertyType), "Cannot use PropertyComparer unless it can be compared by IComparable or ToString");

            _prop = prop;
            _direction = direction;

            if (CanSortWithIComparable(prop.PropertyType))
            {
                var property = typeof(Comparer<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { prop.PropertyType }).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty("Default");
                _comparer = (IComparer)property.GetValue(null, null);
                _useToString = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Assert(
                    CanSortWithToString(prop.PropertyType),
                    "Cannot use PropertyComparer unless it can be compared by IComparable or ToString");

                _comparer = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;
                _useToString = true;
            }
        }

        public override int Compare(T left, T right)
        {
            var leftValue = _prop.GetValue(left);
            var rightValue = _prop.GetValue(right);

            if (_useToString)
            {
                leftValue = leftValue != null ? leftValue.ToString() : null;
                rightValue = rightValue != null ? rightValue.ToString() : null;
            }

            return _direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending
                       ? _comparer.Compare(leftValue, rightValue)
                       : _comparer.Compare(rightValue, leftValue);
        }

        public static bool CanSort(Type type)
        {
            return CanSortWithToString(type) || CanSortWithIComparable(type);
        }

        private static bool CanSortWithIComparable(Type type)
        {
            return type.GetInterface("IComparable") != null ||
                   (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>));
        }

        private static bool CanSortWithToString(Type type)
        {
            return type.Equals(typeof(XNode)) || type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(XNode));
        }
    }
}

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static BindingList<T> ToSortableBindingList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return new SortableBindingList<T>(source.ToList());
    }
}
```

**Example**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
        .Select(x => new { A = x, B = $"x" })
        .ToSortableBindingList();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
}
```