# Why aren't DataGridView columns sortable?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, generic-list

I have a `DataGridView` in a Windows Forms Application. I've marked several columns' `SortMode` to `Automatic`. These are `DataGridViewTextBoxColumns`.

When I click the column headers, nothing happens. Does something else need to be enabled?

I am using a `List<T>` as data source for `DataGridView`.

Comment: What's the datasource for grid?

Comment: List<> of type custom class.

Comment: `List<T>` can not be sorted autimatically. You will find this post helpful: [DataGridView Sort by click on column headers - using Generic Lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37996409/datagridview-sort-by-click-on-column-headers-using-generic-lists)

Comment: When you click on a column header in a data-bound `DataGridView` which its automatic sorting is enabled, first it checks if the list behind of the `DataSource` property is `IBindingList`, then using `SupportsSorting` checks if the list supports sorting. Then it calls `ApplySort` method to sort the list. To have automatic support for sorting in a `DataGridView`, the list should implement `IBindingList` and its members which are related to sort. `SortableBindingList<T>` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Reza: This would make a nice answer, imo..

Comment: @Taw I've posted the answer here: [DataGridView Sort by click on column headers - using Generic Lists](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37999726/3110834).

Comment: @RezaAghaei: Post an answer here. You already have it typed.

Comment: @Neolisk Thank you, I've posted the answer for the duplicate question. Hope users find it useful :)

Comment: This is the best answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770857/how-do-i-implement-automatic-sorting-of-datagridview. Although it isn't actually marked as answered but works great.

Comment: You asked *Why aren't DataGridView columns sortable?* and the duplicate answer exactly says the reason. Also you asked for a solution and the duplicate answer also shares the solution. The link which you shared is OK too, it also mentioned *...I found this implementation of SortableBindingList(Of T) to be the best solution ...*. The duplicate question also shares a Microsoft implementation and an MSDN article implementation of `SortableBindingList<T>`. So I believe the current duplicate is better :)

Comment: Anyway, the good news is knowing that your question has been answered and using `SortableBindingList<T>` you will be in correct direction. When you find such useful answer like the one that you shared or the one that marked as exact duplicate, it would be nice to vote for both questions and answers to bring them higher in search results and make them more useful for future readers.

Comment: MSDN examples are the worst.

Comment: @RezaAghaei: How do you vote them that way?

Comment: By click on up arrow near the question and up arrow near the answer. This way you can vote for good questions and answers. Like me and another one, voted for your question ;)

Comment: Great! Just upvoted that particular question and answer.