# Datagrid view - Cant sort the data

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, datagridview

I am using a stored procedure to return data to my datagrid view, but clicking the header does nothing when I want it to sort.

I used a tutorial to get this far so I dont really understand whats going on.

I have used google to try and find the problem but it talks about list and binding lists but i just dont understand it.

Can anyone see the problem below?

```
public Form_ManagerChanges()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            UpdateBinding();
        }
private void UpdateBinding()
        {

            OccupanciesFoundDataGrid.DataSource = Occupancies;
            OccupanciesFoundDataGrid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = 
            DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
        }  

public class DataAccess
    {
        public List<Occupancies> GetOccupancies (string searchText, string searchType)
        {
            using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("HRIS_DB")))
            {
                if (searchType == "Personal Reference")
                {
                    var output = connection.Query<Occupancies>("hris.spManagerChangeTool_GetByPersonalRef @PersonalRef", new { PersonalRef = searchText }).ToList();
                    return output;
                }
                else if (searchType == "Forename")
                {
                    var output = connection.Query<Occupancies>("hris.spManagerChangeTool_GetByForename @Forname", new { Forname = searchText }).ToList();
                    return output;
                }
                else if (searchType == "Surname")
                {
                    var output = connection.Query<Occupancies>("hris.spManagerChangeTool_GetBySurname @Surname", new { Surname = searchText }).ToList();
                    return output;
                }
                else if (searchType == "Reporting Unit")
                {
                    var output = connection.Query<Occupancies>("hris.spManagerChangeTool_GetByReportingUnit @ReportingUnit", new { ReportingUnit = searchText }).ToList();
                    return output;
                }
                else
                {
                    var output = connection.Query<Occupancies>("hris.spManagerChangeTool_GetByMgrPersonalRef @MgrPersonalRef", new { MgrPersonalRef = searchText }).ToList();
                    return output;
                }
            }
        }






public class Occupancies
    {
        [DisplayName("Personal Reference")]
        public string PERSONAL_REFERENCE { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Forename")]
        public string FORENAME { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Surname")]
        public string SURNAME { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Level 3")]
        public string STRUCTURE_LVL3 { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Level 4")]
        public string STRUCTURE_LVL4 { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Level 5")]
        public string STRUCTURE_LVL5 { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Level 6")]
        public string STRUCTURE_LVL6 { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Level 7")]
        public string STRUCTURE_LVL7 { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Reporting Unit")]
        public string REPORTING_UNIT { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Post Reference")]
        public string POST_REFERENCE { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Post")]
        public string POST { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Position Reference")]
        public string POSITION_REFERENCE { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Position")]
        public string POSITION_NAME { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Mgr - Personal Reference")]
        public string MGR_PERSONAL_REFERENCE { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Mgr - Forename")]
        public string MGR_FORENAME { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Mgr - Surname")]
        public string MGR_SURNAME { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Mgr - Position Reference")]
        public string MGR_POSITION_REFERENCE { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Mgr - Position")]
        public string MGR_POSITION { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: If you're using WinForms then you'll have to implement sorting yourself on header click. Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553100/how-to-enable-datagridview-sorting-when-user-clicks-on-the-column-header

Comment: SQL server stores and retrieves data in random order due to the Server being multi-threaded.  So you must include a ORDER By in the stored procedure to order the data.