# Sorting time data which contain a days hours minutes and seconds in a datagridview C#

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

I have data that needs to be sorted, clicking on datgridview headers, everything works correctly until when I want to sort time data that is in the form **0:00** which means 0 minutes and 0 seconds up to **7-00:00:00** which means 7 days 0 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds (everything is stored in strings).

I currently use this code for sorting, which is from 
[[How to enable DataGridView sorting when user clicks on the column header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553100/how-to-enable-datagridview-sorting-when-user-clicks-on-the-column-header][1])

This code does not work properly when, for example, sorting **ascending** receives **17:25:43 before 2:06:38, 1-02:35:22 before 17:25:43**

Does anyone have any idea how I could sort it correctly clicking a header of datagirdview?

````
private bool _sortDirection;

private void gridView_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == _previousIndex)
        _sortDirection ^= true; // toggle direction

    gridView.DataSource = SortData(
        (List<MainGridViewModel>)gridReview.DataSource, gridReview.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name, _sortDirection);

    _previousIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
}

public List<MainGridViewModel> SortData(List<MainGridViewModel> list, string column, bool ascending)
{
    return ascending ? 
        list.OrderBy(_ => _.GetType().GetProperty(column).GetValue(_)).ToList() :
        list.OrderByDescending(_ => _.GetType().GetProperty(column).GetValue(_)).ToList();
}```
````

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see what type it thinks it is (assuming DateTime) and how it's converted it? It may well be that you need to tell it how to handle DateTime based on a given format.

Comment: Looks like you have combination of strings and DateTime object in the column.  First get all the data to display in the same format.

Comment: @sr28 These are all strings, I download them from a file

Comment: So then it will be sorting based on a string value. Surely in this case you want to convert your date string values to DateTime objects before sorting. As a list of DateTime they will be easier to work with.

Comment: When sorting data, always convert the data to the intended type. Sort integers as such.  Sort dates as such.  When you sort these types as strings, you will see undesired results. For example, a sorted list of numbers (as strings) would look like: `1, 10, 11, 12, 13, ..., 19, 2, 20, ...`

Comment: I used TimeSpan that solved my problem, thanks for the commitment